# Прокрутка вниз на открывшийся блок

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, прокрутка

есть кнопка `<button id="cb-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#cb">Кнопка</button>` , которая раскрывает/закрывает блок 
`<div id="cb" class="row collapse"><!-- Содержимое --></div>`. Как написать скрипт, который при раскрытии блока совершал бы прокрутку вниз на размер блока?
На пример `$("#cb-btn").click(function(){if($(#cb раскрылся) прокрутить вниз на его высоту})`?

Answer (score 0):

В код, который открывает блок, добавьте:

```
$('html, body').scrollTop($('body').scrollTop()+height);
```

Если вы хотите сделать плавную анимацию прокрутки:

```
$('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $('body').scrollTop()+height
        }, 1000);
```

Однако, вам нужно узнать размер блока (height). Если он фиксированный или это не имеет принципиального значения, то задайте в цифрах. Если нет, то 2 варианта:

1. Подождать завершение анимации раскрытия блока
2. Узнать размер элемента с помощью плагина: http://dreamerslab.com/blog/en/get-hidden-elements-width-and-height-with-jquery/

Comment: Используется bootstrap, соответственно collapse бутстраповский, пытался понять куда там можно вставить эту строку, но так и не понял. Хотелось бы написать отдельный скрипт, который бы выполнял обработку `$(#cb-btn).click(function(){if(div раскрывается) прокрутка вниз на n пикселей})`